# SPD 2013. Is it possible to send a email that use's a linked lookup list

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, sharepoint-email, workflow2013

I have a workflow running that looks at a Resource List A. When new starters arrive it sends the email which includes a Location field which is a lookup from List B. Within List A i also display Country and Region that are also pulled in from List B via the main link/lookup field Location.

I would like to also include the country field from List B in the email, but it doesn't appear as a field.
Any ideas how i can include this without creating it as another direct lookup?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that in the list A, there's a lookup column to show location values from list B, and the lookup column has a additional column to show country and region values from list B.

By design, the additional column of lookup column does not display as a link in the workflow email. Create another lookup column is the only way.